# Elastic search update script to return a value

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, return

I am working on a script which updates a nested field of an index. Basically it adds new nested doc. I want to update the script to return the total count of the nested docs for that field also.

Here is structure

Index : topic
nested field: users_read

Whenever a new user reads, his name gets added to "users_read". This happens through script.

I want to modify the script to return the value of number of users_read.

```
{
                "_index": "topic",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "11111",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "11111",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "users_read": "div.sar@abc.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "users_read": "admin2@xyz.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "users_read": "admin"
                        },
                        {
                            "users_read": "admin2@def.com"
                        }
                    ]
        }
}
```

Here is the script i am using

POST - http://elasticserver:9200/topic/_update/11111

```
{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.users.add(params.user)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "user": {
                "users_read":"admin2@dfg.com"
            }
        },
        "source": "ctx._source.users.size()"
    }
}
```

But i am seeing an exception

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                "reason": "[10:19] [script] failed to parse field [source]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[10:19] [UpdateRequest] failed to parse field [script]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
            "reason": "[10:19] [script] failed to parse field [source]",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "must only use one of [source, id] when specifying a script"
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

When i remove the "source" part, script updates the field.

```
POST - http://elasticserver:9200/topic/_update/11111

{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.users.add(params.user)",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "user": {
                "users_read":"admin2@dfg.com"
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "_index": "topic",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "11111",
    "_version": 4,
    "result": "updated",
    "_shards": {
        "total": 2,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "_seq_no": 3,
    "_primary_term": 1
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you would have to use aggregation for it, i don't think if we can use source with script.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the "source" from the script. Having both source and inline in single script will not work.